# Run a function that calls itself every 50 ms and return value when a condition is true

Tags: javascript

I want a code able to know if certain html element is present.
I use a recursive call inside timeout.
Maybe can be another way to make this, but I'm interested to know how to write this code.

```
if (exist("an_id")!==null)
{ ..... }

function exist (id)
{ times =20;
  var el;
 function get_el (callback) 
 { 
    el =  document.getElementById(_id);      
    if (el==null )
    {
           if (--times==0) 
           callback();     
           else
            setTimeout( function () {get_el()}, 50);
    }
    else
    callback();
 }
 get_el ( function (){return el;}); // first call. pass callback.
}
```

This code apparently run ok, 'el' is detected or not after the 'times' specified, but function 'exist' does not return nothing.

I'm some confused. Any help would be appreciated.-

Comment: confusing.....not getting anything out it

Comment: No return in exist? Or do I miss something? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: Why such unreadable code indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you did say that you're interested in finding out how to write the code in the way you were doing it, so I made some modifications, but tried to keep it as similar to your code as possible.

The most relevant change I made was passing the callback to `exist` instead of to `get_el`. This way, the callback function is 'kept alive' until the recursive timeout finishes. You need to run your *"this element exists"* code inside of the callback, though, since this is "asynchronous".

I also changed some of the indentation/addes braces, since your code was quite confusing for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/bro2nvtz/4/

```js
function exist(id, callback) {
    var times = 20;
    var el;
    // Added some more console longs and additional calls to `callback`
    // so it's easy to keep track of what's going on
    function get_el() {
        el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!el) {
            console.log("Trying... " + times);
            callback(el);
            if (--times == 0) {
                console.log("Giving up...");
                callback(el);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    get_el()
                }, 50);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Found it!");
            callback(el);
        }
    }
    get_el();
}
// The way you were doing things, the callback was only getting passed once, and then, it was undefined.
// I think it's a better idea to pass it to the `exist` function, so that it persists as long as
// the timeout is still running.
// For some reason, you were also using _id instead of id. Typo?
exist('dinosaur', function(el) {
  
    // Inside of this callback, run the code that you wish to run
    // when the element exists (or when it doesn't).
    console.log( 'Is it there?: ' + (el ? 'yes! id: ' + el.id : 'no') );
  
    // If it exists...
    if(el) {
      console.log("+------------------------------+");
      console.log("I know for sure it exists, yay!");
      console.log("+------------------------------+");
      setTimeout(function () { 
        el.style.opacity = '1';
      }, 200);
    }
  
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  
});

// For testing...
// Logger and a timeout that appends the img after 500ms

(function () {
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : message) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
        }
    }
})();

// Creates and appends an img of id `dinosaur` to the body, after 500ms.
// Increase the timeout to something like 5000ms and your script will give up.
setTimeout(function () {
    var dinosaur = document.createElement('img');
    dinosaur.id = 'dinosaur';
    dinosaur.src = 'http://www.enchantedlearning.com/tgifs/Trexskelanim.gif';
    dinosaur.style.cssText = 'opacity: 0; transition: all 500ms;';
    document.body.appendChild(dinosaur);
}, 750);
```

```css
html, body {
    background: #000;
}
pre {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't just use the [return value of a synchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/1348195). Your condition will always evaluate to false.

You can encapsulate it in a function that returns a promise or takes a callback:

```
function exists(id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ // old browsers need polyfill
        setTimeout(function check(){ 
           if(document.getElemenyById(id)) resolve();
           else setTimeout(check, 50);
        }, 50);
    });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
exists("someID").then(function(){
   // here the element exists
});
```